# Creating CosmosDB with Azure CLI in powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cli

I'm trying to create a new cosmosdb but getting the below error when I execute below code.

```
az cosmosdb create --name TIC_Test
                    --resource-group "TIC" 
                    --default-consistency-level  Session  
                    --locations "Central US"=0 "Central US"=0 
                    --max-interval 5  --max-staleness-prefix 100  
                    --enable-automatic-failover false  
                    --enable-virtual-network false  
                    --kind GlobalDocumentDB
```

Error:

```
az : usage: az cosmosdb create [-h] [--verbose] [--debug]
At line:2 char:1
+ az cosmosdb create --name TIC_Test --resource-group "TIC"  --default- ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (usage: az cosmo...bose] [--debug]:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

                          [--output {json,jsonc,table,tsv}] [--query JMESPATH]
                          --resource-group RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME --name
                          ACCOUNT_NAME [--locations LOCATIONS [LOCATIONS ...]]
                          [--tags [TAGS [TAGS ...]]]
                          [--kind {GlobalDocumentDB,MongoDB,Parse}]
                          [--default-consistency-level {Eventual,Session,BoundedStaleness,Strong,ConsistentPrefix}]
                          [--max-staleness-prefix MAX_STALENESS_PREFIX]
                          [--max-interval MAX_INTERVAL]
                          [--ip-range-filter IP_RANGE_FILTER [IP_RANGE_FILTER ...]]
                          [--enable-automatic-failover [{true,false}]]
                          [--capabilities CAPABILITIES [CAPABILITIES ...]]
                          [--enable-virtual-network [{true,false}]]
                          [--virtual-network-rules VIRTUAL_NETWORK_RULES [VIRTUAL_NETWORK_RULES ...]]
                          [--subscription _SUBSCRIPTION]
az cosmosdb create: error: list index out of range
```

Any idea of what could be the cause of the error ?

I'm suspecting about this line but I'm not sure how can be specified:

```
 --locations "Central US"=0 "Central US"=0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `--locations` seems to be the problem. According to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/cosmosdb?view=azure-cli-latest#az-cosmosdb-create):

> Space-separated locations in 'regionName=failoverPriority' format. E.g
>   eastus=0 westus=1. Failover priority values are 0 for write regions
>   and greater than 0 for read regions. A failover priority value must be
>   unique and less than the total number of regions. Default: single
>   region account in the location of the specified resource group.

So for example, this works for configuring CentralUS as the read/write region and EastUS as a read region:

```
--locations "CentralUS=0" "EastUS=1"
```

Comment: Thanks so much, the problme was the format that I was using, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

The **--locations** option allows you the specify the failover priority.

Find below an example that creates a new CosmosDB/SQL account, where **East US is primary (Read-Write)** and **West US is secondary (Read-Only)**.

```
az cosmosdb create --name "cosmosdb5555" --kind GlobalDocumentDB --resource-group "cosmosdbrg" --locations "eastus=0", "westus=1"
```

You are observing an error because the **--locations** you specified is invalid due to duplicated regions and syntax.

The following error will be thrown if you specify duplicated regions in **--locations**:

```
Operation failed with status: 'BadRequest'. Details: Failover priorities must be unique and 0 <= priority < (number of failover policies)
ActivityId: 689752f6-8081-11e8-8a4b-9cb6d00f36f2, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.0.0.0
```